# After payment for payment status api give http 400 error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
CreateCheckoutFormInitializeRequest request = new CreateCheckoutFormInitializeRequest();
request.Locale = Locale.TR.ToString();
request.Price = "1";
request.PaidPrice = "1.2";
request.Currency = Currency.TRY.ToString();
request.PaymentGroup = PaymentGroup.PRODUCT.ToString();
request.CallbackUrl = "https://www.merchant.com/callback";
```

this callback url is get my payment status page. But it give http400 error. I am using .net core 2.1. Is ı need any permission on startup or appsettings page?

Comment: 400 means "Bad Request", so your `request` or some its field is wrong.

Comment: Payment is succesful. After payment api return a token and open CALLBACKURL ..it this url give http 400 error.. is a need a permission that api url open my this page?